# How to get the number after the decimal position in RPGLE program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a PF in a rpgle program  with a field having values 1001.123, 1001.234, 1001.561 and so on. I need to capture the number after the decimal position for doing some calculations. So I need to fetch 123 from 1001.123 , get 234 from 1001.234 and so on.

Can some one tell me how to achieve this in RPGLE?

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is an unsigned integer, you can do it like this, provided the integer part of `your_var` fits in a `int(10)`.

```
decimals = %int((your_var - %int(your_var)) * 10 ** %decpos(your_var))
```

If performance is critical and your_var is defined as `packed(7:3)` then this would be better

```
decimals = %abs(your_var - %dec(your_var:7:0)) * 1000.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with a data structure as well

```
**free
dcl-ds *n;
  your_var zoned(10: 3);
  your_decimals zoned(3: 0) pos(8);
end-ds;

dcl-s msg char(50);

your_var = 1001.123;
msg = %trim(%char(your_var)) + '=>' + %trim(%char(your_decimals));
dsply msg;

*inlr = *on;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the whole number using %dec with 0 decimal and substract it from your var:

your_var - %dec(your_var : 0 )

Comment: That would result in `0000.123`

Comment: The second parameter for %DEC is the length of the result, so you need %dec(yourvar : 7 : 0).